# Check if another app handles A URL scheme that your app handles

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, url-scheme

I will to check if another iOS application installed on a device handles a URL scheme. I can easily do that with the `canOpenURL(_:)`.

The catch is my app also implements the same URL scheme but I only want my application to handle calls to the URL if no other application on the device handles it.

Answer (score 1):

As you might've noticed, Apple values its users' privacy with utmost priority. Similarly, it also values its developers. Your task at hand at hand requires accessing the code of another application — which (un)fortunately is not possible.

Comment: I am not sure I will need to access another code's application. I want to call `canOpenURL(_:)` but exclude my own application from the list of possibilities. Is this clear?

Comment: Your question says, "if no other application on the device handles it" - How do you intend to check this?

Comment: If no other application handles it, I will like my app to handle the URL call. That is the question. How do I check that no other application on the device handles this URL scheme?

Comment: "no other application on the device handles this URL scheme" - You need to access other applications' code to check if they handle it or not.

Comment: Kunal, a call to `canOpenURL(_:)` will return true if there is an app that can handle the URL parameter passed to the method. The question is how can I exclude my app from this check?